# Computer Vision and AR libraries availabe for Android?

Tags: android, opencv, computer-vision, augmented-reality, google-vision

I am starting out as an Android Developer, and I would like to know if there are any Computer vision libraries or Augmented Reality libraries for the Android SDK, as I am planning to use these libraries for a mobile app.

I have read that if I download the NDK, I might be able to "import/use" the C openCV, and ARtoolkit libraries, but I am wondering if this is possible, or if there is a better and easier way of using these tools.

Android apps are programmed in Java, yet OpenCV & ARtoolkit use C/C++. Is there any way to use these libraries?

Comment: Users of ARToolKit have two options for Android, both of which support JDK programming. ARToolKit Professional for Android uses native code internally, but exposes this to the JDK through a nice interface. Alternately, you can use AndAR which is Java based.

Answer (score 8):

There are [a number of wrappers for OpenCV](http://computerblindness.blogspot.com/2010/01/opencv-bindings.html) available. For Java you might check [JavaCV](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/) out.

To my knowledge, there is GSoC activity on [AR with OpenCV on Android](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/AugmentedRealityStreetViewAndroid), but they seem to use C++.

Answer (score 6):

Qualcomm is working on an [Augmented Library for Android](http://www.qdevnet.com/ar).   As was mentioned opencv is also an option.

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to know if there are any
>   Computer vision libraries or Augmented
>   Reality libraries for the Android SDK

In the SDK? No. There are existing AR applications for Android (Layar, WIKITUDE) that you may wish to use as your foundation.

> Is there any way to use these
>   libraries?

A quick search via Google turns up [this](http://github.com/billmccord/OpenCV-Android) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232074/opencv-ndk-android-help).

Answer (score 3):

Layar has made [**Layar Vision**](http://www.layar.com/documentation/browser/howtos/layar-vision-doc/) available to developers:

> Layar Vision uses detection, tracking and computer vision techniques
> to augment objects in the physical world. We can tell which objects in
> the real world are augmented because the fingerprints of the object
> are preloaded into the application based upon the user’s layer
> selection. When a user aims their device at an object that matches the
> fingerprint, we can quickly return the associated AR experience.
>
> *[...]*
>
> Layar Vision will be applied to the following Layar products:
>
> - 6.0 version of **Layar Reality browser on Android** and iPhone iOS platforms.
> - iPhone Layar Player SDK v2.0.
> - The first release of an **Android Layar Player SDK**.
> - Layar Connect v2.0.

The simplest solution is to [create a Vision layer](http://www.layar.com/documentation/browser/howtos/layar-vision-doc/enable-layar-vision-layer/), then use [launcher creator for Android](http://www.layar.com/documentation/browser/howtos/layar-vision-doc/enable-layar-vision-layer/) to create a layer launching app.

Answer (score 1):

You can code in Java using [OpenCV4Android](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html), the official Android port of OpenCV.  If you want to use native C++ OpenCV code, check out the [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

There's a new option for CV on Android, the [Google Mobile Vision API](https://developers.google.com/vision/). The API is exposed through `com.google.android.gms.vision` and lets you detect various types of objects (faces, barcodes, and facial features) given an arbitrary image bitmap.

In addition, Google provides the [Cardboard VR library](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/) and a [Unity plugin](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/unity/) to make it easier for you to develop VR applications - such applications could include AR based on Mobile Vision if you integrated the phone's camera.

Comment: I assume it's not possible to use the Google Mobile Vision API in a Unity app, right?

Comment: It is possible - I'm not sure Google provides a plugin currently though.

Answer (score 1):

## Now Google offers us 2 powerful SDKs: [ARCore](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/) and [ML Kit](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/).

`ARCore` API has such important features as Augmented Images, Augmented Faces and Cloud Anchors. It supports Kotlin/Java languages, debugging apps on Emulator (AVD) and physically based rendering (PBR) with a help of Sceneform.

`ML Kit` API brings Google’s machine learning expertise to mobile developers in a powerful and easy-to-use package. Although ML Kit is still in beta stage it allows you to work with such important features as: Image Labelling, Text Recognition, Face Detection, Barcode Scanning, and Landmark Detection.